# PS1 window title under PuTTY with GNU screen

Tags: putty, gnu-screen, ps1

I'm currently setting my PS1 title with by concatinating three variables in my .bashrc in such a way:

```
export TERMSERVER=`who am i | awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d ')''('`
if [ -n "$TERMSERVER" ] ; then
  PS1_TITLE='\h ($MACHTYPE) - $SHELL[$SHLVL] <-- $TERMSERVER'
else
  PS1_TITLE='\h ($MACHTYPE) - $SHELL[$SHLVL]'
fi
export PS1="$PS1_TITLE\n$PS1_LINE\n$PS1_PROMPT"
```

I also open up several PuTTY and launch a different GNU screen in each PuTTY, each with a session name, eg:

```
screen -T screen -U -S session-1 (in PuTTY #1)
screen -T screen -U -S session-2 (in PuTTY #1)
```

I'ld love to see *session-1* or *session-2* appear in my PuTTY window title, but I can't find a correct .screenrc configuration of *hardstring* working.
I also can't find a method to correctly map the contents of "/var/run/screen/S-user" to my current session. I tried using ${PPID}, but it'll fail if in a subshell.

Excerpt from my current .screenrc:

```
# Every x seconds, requery window title                     
backtick 1 600 600 id -un                                   

# The window's title                                        
hardstatus ignore        
# *** this is the current window title I use since I can't get what I want.
hardstatus string "%1`@%H"                               

caption always                                              
caption string "%{= KW}%-w%{= wk}%50>%n %t%{-}%+w%< %=%H %l"
```

Is there any method to obtain what I want?

Comment: Screen versions:
- Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
- Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06

Comment: Did you try asking in a the Ubuntu forums? It seems more like something those gurus would know about.

Comment: @ppumkin: The machines are CentOs and Debian. Anyway, I prefer asking on StackOverflow than on an Ubuntu forum; Ubuntu users probably lurk here too ;-)

Comment: Well yea even if its centos or wahteverOS-- It still core Linux - And no; some clever guys from Ubuntu SE Linux do not venture this side because they are dedicated for support in Ubuntu(Linux) only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that `screen` prints its session name on the PuTTY window title add this function to your `.bashrc`:

```
screen ()
{
    sessionname=$(echo $@ | fgrep -- '-S ' | sed 's/.*-S \([^ ]\+\).*/\1/');
    echo -ne "\033]0;${sessionname:-Putty}\007";
    command screen $@;
    echo -ne "\033]0;Putty\007"
}
```

Run screen as usual.

The function checks for an option called -S , extracts the session name, sets it with terminal escape sequences (or sets Putty if session name is empty) and runs the `screen` binary. When the `screen` binary exits, the PuTTY window title is reset to Putty.

Since seeing is believing :-) :

This is a Putty session ready to execute screen.
[image: Putty session ready to execute screen.]

Inside a screen session. Notice the PuTTY window title.
[image: Inside a screen session. Title is screen session name.]

Screen session ended. Title is reset.
[image: Screen session ended. Title is Putty.]